# downloading videos to a specific path with youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I cant seem to find a way to download videos with youtube-dl to a specific path, I have tried -o but it just does something and says that it downloaded to that path but there are no videos there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set up default download location in youtube-dl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482230/how-to-set-up-default-download-location-in-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 0):

Use `-o`, but don't forget to include an actual template, [as documented](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template):

```
youtube-dl -o '/target/directory/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s' BaW_jenozKc
```

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl --no-check-certificate --console-title --retries infinite "%url%" --verbose --restrict-filenames --output "%%UserProfile%%/Downloads/%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"

Answer (score -3):

Try m.ss.youtube.com and paste the link of the video you want to download.

Comment: What is the programming link?

Comment: its not just youtube, youtube-dl can download from many different websites so im asking how can I set the path of the installation

Comment: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#output-template-and-windows-batch-files